# Deep nested types

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am newby in typescript. therefore could someone describe me how to realize this type of deep nested object programatically:

```js
type typeDeepNestedGeneric<T> = T
    | {[key: string]: T}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}}}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}}}}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}}}}}
    | {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: T}}}}}}}
```

in my class object I want to define properties with objects with unlimited depth of types included:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy?

```
type DeepNestedGeneric<T> = T | {[key: string]: DeepNestedGeneric<T> }

const x : DeepNestedGeneric<string> = {
     foo: "wsdfhsdf",
     bar: {
          whatever: "akjdhakjs",
          baz: {
               blerg: "dsfsdsdfsd",
               errors: 5 // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DeepNestedGeneric<string>'.
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Seems yes. very strange but I did the same but it didn't work.. thank you!

Comment: consider marking this as the answer then?  (since you're new)